# datetime.datetimes in json are causing "Expecting value" errors in Python

Tags: python, json, datetime

I'm trying to decode some json with the `json` library in Python 3. This is causing an "Expected value..." error:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Using an object_hook doesn't seem to help here, I tried adding one but it never even got called. What's going on?

Comment: What makes you think that that is valid JSON?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? As Martijn says - that's not JSON - but I'm wondering if you've tried to create an example to post here and perhaps simplified it to something that's somewhat misleading to what you may actually be trying to achieve...

Comment: @MartijnPieters It showed up in some JSON I got from an API. I was surprised at first too, but then I found lots of similar python questions with datetime and JSON and I figured it was just some JSON feature I hadn't been aware of.

Comment: @JackM: but then those values are inside *JSON strings*, they are not the JSON document themselves. `json.loads('"datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)"')` works and produces the Python string `"datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)"`. Note the single quotes, the double quotes are part of the JSON document.

Comment: @MartijnPieters They were outside of quotes - but I've realized the problem. I used a particular python module to download the JSON, but what I didn't realize is it doesn't just straight download the data, it attempts to convert it into python-readable data. Thus date strings become datetimes... Thanks for the nudge in the right direction, I would have just gone on thinking I was looking at valid json for another two hours probably.

Comment: @JackM: at which point the library has post-processed the parsed JSON and has detected what values are actually interpretable as datetime values and has done the conversion for you.

Comment: I think it's really cool how the community here will downvote questions for not knowing that answer to their own question ahead of time. If I had the knowledge to recognize what is and isn't JSON, I'd be answering questions instead of asking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.loads()` only accepts valid JSON data. You don't have valid JSON. You can't put Python object names in there.

The object hook only applies to `{....}` *JSON* objects. The term *object* here does not extend to the Python definition.

If you want to put datetime values into JSON, you'll need to come up with a different scheme. JSON does not have any native support; usually the specific API just documents what values are supposed to be datetime values, and when reading the JSON data you handle dates on the application level, not at the decoding level.

If you found `"datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)"` *strings* in a JSON document, then as far as the JSON parser is concerned those are just strings. The contents of the string are not processed, that's up to the application layer to do.

If these strings are values inside a JSON object (`{"key": "datetime.datetime(...)", ...}`), then you *could* use the `object_hook` callback to inspect all such values and replace them with `datetime` instances:

```
import datetime, re

datetime_pat = re.compile(r'datetime\.datetime\([\d, ]+\)')

def convert_datetime_values(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if datetime.pat.match(value):
            d[key] = eval(value)
    return d
```

You can't do the same for JSON arrays however.

Comment: I've seen some systems dump out `"datetime.datetime(...)"` as values - still not sure if the OP has simplified their question down too much and they *are* dealing with JSON but are trying to work out how to handle where that appears.

Comment: @JonClements: But those are still strings that the application layer then has to interpret. The JSON library has no facilities to interpret those.

Comment: I know that :) I was just pointing out the question asked and the problem shown isn't likely to be what the question is actually meant to be asking - but you've addressed that in edits :p

Comment: I find the `demjson` module useful for less JSON-y JSON (or for more convenient hooks than the builtin module provides)... Feel free to add from https://gist.github.com/anonymous/552d2984c18ef28fa7f39c8b7ebcf3cd if you want